# apache 2.4 lot of stuck threads in "W" sending reply mode

Tags: apache2.4, rhel7

I just upgraded Apache webserver from 2.2 to 2.4. After upgrade, I am getting lot of stuck threads in W mode. I am not using php. The stuck threads are happening even on static html pages or while doing load testing via Jmeter.

Because of these stuck threads, it is reaching the MaxRequestWorkers/MaxClients Limit and server becomes non-responsive. Memory is not an issue. Since even during the server crash I had about 10Gb of free memory.

Just to verify if it is Apache, I swithced it back to 2.2 (old server) and no more hung threads!

ServerTokens OS
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
PidFile run/httpd.pid
TimeOut 295
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15

StartServers      20
MinSpareServers   15
MaxSpareServers   40
ServerLimit      1024

## MaxClients       2048

MaxRequestWorkers 2048

## MaxRequestsPerChild  5000

MaxConnectionsPerChild 5000

Following is the pstack on one fo the threads:

pstack 30078

```
#0  0x00007f0c6536df4d in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f0c65369d02 in _L_lock_791 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00007f0c65369c08 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007f0c58e53f4b in yodysMtxLock () from /etc/httpd/modules/libdms2.so
#4  0x00007f0c58e518e6 in yodSlotLock () from /etc/httpd/modules/libdms2.so
#5  0x00007f0c58e50266 in yodStateIncrementSb8 () from        /etc/httpd/modules/libdms2.so
#6  0x00007f0c597ca764 in wl_increment_state_metric () from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wl_24.so
#7  0x00007f0c597c5af9 in request_handler () from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wl_24.so
#8  0x00007f0c668dc290 in ap_run_handler ()
#9  0x00007f0c668dc7d9 in ap_invoke_handler ()
#10 0x00007f0c668f0bca in ap_process_async_request ()
#11 0x00007f0c668f0ea4 in ap_process_request ()
#12 0x00007f0c668ed7f2 in ap_process_http_connection ()
#13 0x00007f0c668e5890 in ap_run_process_connection ()
#14 0x00007f0c58c2280f in child_main () from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#15 0x00007f0c58c22a55 in make_child () from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#16 0x00007f0c58c22ab6 in startup_children () from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#17 0x00007f0c58c237c0 in prefork_run () from  /etc/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#18 0x00007f0c668c25be in ap_run_mpm ()
#19 0x00007f0c668bbb46 in main ()
```

Any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: Can you grab a quick pstack output of one of the httpd child processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particular thread is stuck in the proprietary weblogic plugin waiting on a lock. It's surprising it manages to trigger even on static requests. But it's something you'll need to take up with the vendor, nobody else can debug it.

Comment: It's a behaviour I'm seeing even now with latest module version.